# Java XML split inter-line FRC

Tags: java, xml, twitter, line, newline

Okay, so, I am trying to parse an XML file in Java.
Mp>I get the line I need from the feed and then I can print it, but I need to split it into multiple lines.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/20081392/FRCFMSTwitterParse/)!

although, line 31 needs to be changed to

```
    File fXmlFile = new File("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=frcfms");
```

I need to take the output of that:

```
Tweet : frcfms: #FRCDEV1 TY P MC 6 RF 50 BF 179 RA 5 10 8 BA 4 2 3 RC 30 BC 30 RFP 0 BFP 0 RAS 0 BAS 60 RTS 20 BTS 89
```

and split it into a new line after each 2 letter code, and I would like to change the two letter code to the respective word, the document for which is avaliable [here](http://www.usfirst.org/sites/default/files/uploadedFiles/Robotics_Programs/FRC/Game_and_Season__Info/2013/2013FMSTwitterFeed_Rev0.pdf)

so hopefully, it would look like this-ish

```
    Tweet : frcfms #EVENT
    TY(pe) : Q(ualification)
    M(atch) C(ount) : ***
    R(ed) F(inal) : ***
    etc...
```

Avoidence of RegEx would be nice, if possiable...I get real lost, real easy

Commits are welcome!

Comment: what does `Commits are welcome!`  mean

Comment: commit to the github repo

Comment: also, i got it, using RegEx anyways...thanks IRC

Comment: cool bud, you're sharp! hope you the best

Comment: well...the regex hates me...but theres a python version of basically what i need on github...ugh...5 hours wasted